# how set white color filter on drawable in Java Android

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I have a drawable:

```
Drawable drawable = Theme.getCachedWallpaper();
```

and I have a view that I need set this drawable on this view:

```
fragmentView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

but I need set this drawable with white (or red or black and ...) color filter such :

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FrameLayout and create extra blank layout above your image. You can set background and alpha values programmatically as below

```
yourview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
yourview.setAlpha(0.5f);    // alpha value ranges from 0.0f to 1.0f
```

Answer (score 0):

-You can set alpha to drawable using setAlpha(int alpha) method.

Comment: what doing if i need set red color?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure th task on your class by calling your layout like this:

```
 RelativeLayout layout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
```

this will be the code inside your if statement to change backgorund:

```
 layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ready);
```